# regarding installing angular plugin by NPM or bower

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower

sorry to ask a very basic question because i am not familiar with NPM and bower. just saw a hint to install a library based on angularjs.

just see it

```
npm install --save angularjs-gauge

bower install --save angularjs-gauge
```

i just like to know where NPM or bower will save the library ?

how can i specify path to save the lib in specific folder with NPM and bower. thanks

Comment: use global flag to install it in the User's folder. If you use --save flag, First you need to have a working project with npm initialized or containing a package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Bower configuration file .bowerrc in the project root and specify the directory path.

e.g:-

{
  "directory" : "public/components"
}

https://bower.io/docs/config/

Run bower install again.

Comment: i am working with visual studio IDE. so tell me how could i instruct npm or bower to install plugin js file it in my project js folder.